# Trouble with AJAX within a form

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a newbie to JavaScript. I tried to use AJAX from within a form and kept getting  "HTTP ERROR 405".

I'd been viewing a video course, so I tested the example code in my environment and it worked perfectly. But the example was not in a form. So I removed the  and  from my code and the AJAX works. But I need this to work in a form. I want to make several AJAX calls to the server within this one form and need to know what to do to make them work.

Here's the failing HTML code:

```
<form id="Match_Results" action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Before the Match</legend>
  <div id="which_league">
    <button id=get_leagues>Get Leagues</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here's the JS:

```
document.getElementById('get_leagues').addEventListener('click', loadData);

function loadData() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'leagues.txt', true);

xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log('READYSTATE', xhr.readyState);
    if(this.status === 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `<h2>${this.responseText}</h2>`;
  }
}

xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.log('Request error...');
}

xhr.send();
```

This is just the first step in getting this to work, so I'm just pulling in a local text file and using a button. Actual code later will do this automatically, without the button, pulling from a MySQL db via a PHP page. But I can't even get this working.

Comment: You have `<div id="which_league">` duplicated

Comment: A `405` indicates that the endpoint you're calling doesn't support the request method. For example, a `POST` to a `GET` endpoint, etc.

Comment: @jefftrotman Thanks, was a typo in copying to SO, fixed in the question.

Comment: @Santi  OK, I get it, the POST will only be needed when I'm pointing to the PHP page. When I deleted the POST section the error disappeared. Thank-you. I can't credit you with the answer, though, until you submit as an answer.